# How to get [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses on remote PC?

Tags: powershell

I run
$ips = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("Server") and get ip 192.168.1.1, for example. It's good.
How can I do same for remote computer?
Thank you

I just cant find a command to connect remote pc and run same code.

Comment: You want `Invoke-Command`: `$remoteIPs = Invoke-Command { [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("Server") } -ComputerName remoteComputer`